# Error building on Windows 10

Tags: windows

One thing I enjoy about open source projects is that you can build from source. I enjoy doing it with other coins and with miners. However with Monero I am having error after error. I am unsure if I am doing something wrong. I am following the steps on the Monero GitHub and the build is failing at 90%. I even tried it on a fresh Windows install and am having the same issue. The first issue is the instructions expect you to clone with git. MYSYS2 doesn't have that as an option as git is not installed. I got around this by following another guide to install git in MYSYS2. Here is a link to my CMake Error Log if that helps. https://docdro.id/fvlIh9Q Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Edit: I have added the console output from the failed build here https://docdro.id/cbURFJn.

Edit: I finally got it to build fully but none of the exe files open.  They attempt to open then close right away.

Comment: What would be more helpful at the moment is the console output of the build process.

Comment: As a side note, you can install git with `pacman -S git`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  The issue was because of the new version of GCC.  There is a fix for the issue in the newest CMake file but I was building the latest release so I just needed to manually apply the fix.  https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/4290/commits/2bc977bab9b9a2fa97e034357606270804a3e0df